# Multiple style/PolyStyle tags in KML file

Tags: xml, google-maps, polygon, kml

Stackers..

I currently seem to be having some trouble with applying styles to polygons in a KML file that I have created.

Currently, I am only trying to style two states, two different colours (North and South Dakota).

When I upload it to a KML validator such as feedvalidator dot org it tells me the file is valid and there is no errors.

When I upload the file/code to a site where it will display the output on a map, I see what I expect. (image 1 below)

The issue is when the file is uploaded to GoogleMaps, it only seems to honor the first style only! (image 2 below)

**Below is a simplified version of my code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
    <name><![CDATA[Landgrab]]></name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Style id="mowhawk">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://www.thefairtradepractice.co.uk/sites/default/files/mowhawk-logo-gmap-pin.png</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
        <LabelStyle>
            <color>8072000B</color>
            <scale>1</scale>
        </LabelStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>8072000B</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>8072000B</color>
            <fill>1</fill>
            <outline>1</outline>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>

    <Style id="sioux">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://www.thefairtradepractice.co.uk/sites/default/files/sioux-logo-gmap-pin.png</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
        <LabelStyle>
            <color>8000FFFF</color>
            <scale>1</scale>
        </LabelStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>8000FFFF</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>8000FFFF</color>
            <fill>1</fill>
            <outline>1</outline>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>

<!--
#############################
    NORTH DAKOTA STATE
#############################
--> 

<Placemark id="pm255">
    <name><![CDATA[North Dakota]]></name>
    <Snippet maxLines="0">empty</Snippet>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#mowhawk</styleUrl>
    <MultiGeometry>
        <Point id="g883">
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            <coordinates>
                *****LIST OF CO-ORDINATES*****
            </coordinates>
        </Point>
        <Polygon id="g884">
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        *****LIST OF CO-ORDINATES*****
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>

<!--
#############################
    SOUTH DAKOTA STATE
#############################
--> 

<Placemark id="pm256">
    <name><![CDATA[South Dakota]]></name>
    <Snippet maxLines="0">empty</Snippet>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <styleUrl>#sioux</styleUrl>
    <MultiGeometry>
        <Point id="g885">
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            <coordinates>
                *****LIST OF CO-ORDINATES*****
            </coordinates>
        </Point>
        <Polygon id="g886">
            <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        *****LIST OF CO-ORDINATES*****
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>

</Document>
</kml>
```

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylvLd.png)

[Actual Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnaG5.png)

As can be seen from the above screen shots, when I put the KML into GoogleMaps, it doesn't seem to pick up any of the styles except for the first one.

**Sites I used to check the output;**

- display-kml.appspot.com/
- elsevier-apps.sciverse.com/GoogleMaps/verification

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried it without the MultiGeomety and just used the Polygon geometry?. Maybe the MultiGeomety is causing the problem.

Comment: Please post the complete KML you are using.  If I take what you posted and add in the missing coordinates, [it works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20151202_MultipleStyle.kml) (at least using the Google Maps Javascript API v3 KmlLayer renderer)

Comment: @JasonM1 I haven't tried using just the Polygon elements but I can give that a go. The problem only happens when I upload it to [GoogleMaps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/)

Comment: @geocodezip I used the website you linked to and attached my file to it and had no issues as shown above in the expected results [link](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://thefairtradepractice.co.uk/sites/default/files/Injuin-landgrab-two-poly.kml). The only thing not included in my snippet above is the co-ordinates

Comment: In that case, seem to be an issue in the KML renderer on Google Maps.  How are  you "uploading it to Google Maps"?  Can you provide a link to the  map/content that doesn't work?  We can't do much with a picture.

Comment: Sure thing. 

Step-by-step;
#1 - I go to https://www.google.com/maps/d/ - #2 create a new layer and hit the import button - #3 upload my KML file - #4 See the output - 

I have created an example [here](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zDck0U_q2mBk.kC0xs7v_36fM&usp=sharing)

Comment: I see what you mean.  Seems to be an issue with My Maps, the second polygon's styling doesn't seem to be used, even if I change to "Individual Styles", and I keep getting errors.  Here is my version created by following those steps: [link](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zNPjLbo835mE.kEIIXX6VN84I)

Comment: It is displaying the correct custom pin icon, just not the colour. What errors are you seeing as I haven't had any come up when i do it?